# Copy multiple sheets to one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code in extendoffice website. However it doesn't meet what I need to do with the sheets. I have also search here unfortunately, it doesn't also meet my requirements.

The code below works great but it saves each worksheet as individual workbook. Basically I have 4 sheets in my main workbook. And the result is, it saves each sheet as one workbook. I wanted it to be the same (Saving in a folder) but worksheets should be saved in one workbook.

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
xWs.Copy
If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    Select Case xWb.FileFormat
        Case 51:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56:
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
    End Select
End If
xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get what I need with the code below:

```
Sub ExportSheets()

Dim wb As Workbook, InitFileName As String, fileSaveName As String

InitFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reminder " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")


  Sheets(Array("SheetName1", "SheetName2", "SheetName3", "SheetName4")).Copy

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitFileName, _
filefilter:="Excel files , *.xlsx")

With wb
    If fileSaveName <> "False" Then

        .SaveAs fileSaveName
        .Close
    Else
        .Close False
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

End Sub
```